# удаление коммита с гита

Tags: git, github

Объясните пожалуйста как удалить ненужный коммит на гитхабе?
У меня сейчас там есть лишний коммит, который мне сказали удалить. Я пытался найти инфу в интернете, но сделал только хуже и вместо удаления коммита вернул проект к первоначальному виду. Благо восстанавливать было немного. Сейчас я вроде бы восстановил, но теперь запушить не могу, гит мне говорит:

```
подсказка: Обновления были отклонены, так как верхушка вашей текущей ветки
подсказка: позади ее внешней части. Заберите и слейте внешние изменения 
подсказка: (например, с помощью «git pull …») перед повторной попыткой отправки
подсказка: изменений.
```

Я слишком тупой для гита, было бы неплохо, если бы вы разъяснили немного ситуацию

Comment: `--force` забыли

Comment: может откатить, а не удалить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git